# defining route with 'auth:web' middleware in laravel service provider boot() method

Tags: laravel, service-provider

im using a package called https://github.com/garygreen/pretty-routes
there is line in its service provider boot() method [(here the code)](https://github.com/garygreen/pretty-routes/blob/ebd9e2328bc213f3c413d4ec7e3aef53801d1646/src/ServiceProvider.php#L41)

it is defining a get route with middlewares from its config file([link to the code](https://github.com/garygreen/pretty-routes/blob/ebd9e2328bc213f3c413d4ec7e3aef53801d1646/config.php#L13)) I just added 'auth:web' to its config file but it seems the 'auth:web' middleware is called as soon as code reaches the line before Laravel bootstraps its session and etc. when the auth('web')->user() is yet **null**

What I can not understand is that I do the same exact thing ([here the code](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/blob/de59dbe011bd88f84752f186093f47d363779be1/config/telescope.php#L78))with laravel/telescope but it works. **why ???**
also changing :

```
Route::get(config('pretty-routes.url'), 'PrettyRoutes\PrettyRoutesController@show')
            ->name('pretty-routes.show')
            ->middleware(config('pretty-routes.middlewares'));
```

to :

```
$this->app['router']->get(config('pretty-routes.url'), 'PrettyRoutes\PrettyRoutesController@show')
            ->name('pretty-routes.show')
            ->middleware(config('pretty-routes.middlewares'));
```

in service provider seems to solve the problem and make this code behave like the way telescope package use 'auth:web' as middleware.
what's happening ?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the only thing happening in that `boot` method is registering a route, nothing is "ran" at that point .... does this route have the "web" middleware group assigned to it? if not then there is no session, therefor no auth

Comment: emmm . added 'web' to middleware part of the mentioned package and the auth('web')->user() is working as expected ! what just happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `web` middleware applied to any routes you need sessions for, which is what the default authentication system is using. When you apply the `auth` middleware without this it can't possibly resolve a user since there is no session to be authenticated against.

You need to apply the `web` middleware and then what ever other middleware you want:

```
'middlewares' => [
    'web', 'auth:web',
],
```

If you look at the telescope example you provided you will see they also add the `web` middleware. So you didn't quite "do the same exact thing" as the telescope config.

Comment: why changing `Route::get` to `$this->app['router']->get` works ? (in service provider boot method)

Comment: because you are in a Service Provider which has an instance of the Application container as a member variable `$app`, so `$this->app` is referring to the Container ... the `Route` facade `Route::....` is using that binding on the container `'router'`, it is making this same call